Simulation: Use of Integrate() in conjunction with custom functions
In attempting to create a simple simulation for psycholinguistics, I have encountered the following error:
> expected_success_rate(170)
> Error in if (height \>= threshold) { : the condition has length \> 1
> Called from: prob_height_given_one(h, thresh)


I think in this case there must be a problem with the definition of expected_success_rate> The example should be reproducible.
height_dist \<- c(177.5, 6.35)

#TWO CASES

#FIRST : h \< θ   --\>  null utterance, u0

# only prior distribution can inform degree of belief that referent is tall to a given degree: φ(h|u0,θ) = φ(h)

prob_height_given_null <- function(height) {
  dnorm(height, mean = height_dist[1], sd = height_dist[2])
}

# SECOND: h >= θ  --> positive form, u1

# if h ≥ θ, then listener can update by conditioning on u1, which yields a new distribution

prob_height_given_one <- function(height, threshold) {
  if (height >= threshold) {
    integrand <- function(x) {
      dnorm(x, mean = height_dist[1], sd = height_dist[2])
    }
    normaliser <- integrate(integrand, threshold, Inf)
    return(prob_height_given_null(height)/normaliser$value)
  }
  else {
    return(0)
  }
}

# Expected success rate (still non-normalised)
expected_success_rate <- function(thresh) {
  integrand_LHS <- function(h) {
    prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_null(h)
    }
  value_LHS <- integrate(integrand_LHS, -Inf, thresh)
  integrand_RHS <- function(h) {
    prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_one(h, thresh)}

  value_RHS <- integrate(integrand_RHS, thresh, Inf)
  
  return(value_LHS$value + value_RHS$value)
}

expected_success_rate(170)

integrate(expected_success_rate, -Inf, true_height)



Firstly, one problem appears to stem from the definitions of integrand_LHS and integrand_RHS.
One suggestion from copilot was to use Vectorize() to define each integrand - but I didn't trust it as I could not wrap my head around the motivation.
Another issue that has cropped up is that I plant to use the Luce-choice rule. Putting normalisation aside for simplicity, the bottom line is that the expected_success_rate will itself require integration to yield the quantity of interest:
integrate(expected_success_rate, -Inf, true_height)



I did experiment with the Vectorize() suggestion within expected_success_rate, as follows:
expected_success_rate <- function(threshold) {
  integrand_LHS <- Vectorize(function(h) prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_null(h))
  value_LHS <- integrate(integrand_LHS, -Inf, threshold)
  
  integrand_RHS <- Vectorize(function(h) prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_one(h, threshold))
  value_RHS <- integrate(integrand_RHS, threshold, Inf)
  
  return(value_LHS$value + value_RHS$value)
}


it seemed to work as plots of expected_success_rate looked plausible.
But then a new error was generated here - as you can see, it appears to stem from the definition of that function.
> integrate(expected_success_rate, -Inf, true_height)
 Error in integrate(integrand_LHS, -Inf, thresh) : 
  length(upper) == 1 is not TRUE


Can anyone help? More broadly, I'd be interested in views as to which languages are best for manipulating bayesian equations.

Instead of integrating dorm, use pnorm. Also unless it's attenuated normal, the normalizing constant is 1. Otherwise it's just pnorm with the lower tail being false

integrate expects the function to be vectorized (it will pass a vector input, and it expects a vector output). if statements are not vectorized, hence the error.
The immediate error can be resolved by surrounding the definition of prob_height_given_one and expected_success_rate by Vectorize.
However, there's no appropriate reason to use integrate here. Squaring the normal PDF results in another normal PDF (with standard deviation equal to sigma/sqrt(2), and then scaled by a constant), so pnorm can be used. I see no reason for the if statement: height will always be greater than threshold based on the integral. This allows expected_success_rate to be greatly simplified:
expected_success_rate2 <- function(thresh) {
  normalizer <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], height_dist[2], FALSE)
  value_LHS <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], s)/height_dist[2]/sqrt(pi)/2
  value_RHS <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], s, FALSE)/C/normalizer
  value_LHS + value_RHS
}

s <- height_dist[2]/sqrt(2)
C <- 2*height_dist[2]*sqrt(pi)

From this we can see that expected_success_rate is integrating a likelihood that is proportional (with a constant that depends on thresh) to a normal distribution. For values less than thresh, it is C, and for values greater than thresh, it is C*normalizer, where normalizer is a function of thresh. This will give a positive value everywhere, so integrating expected_success_rate over a non-finite interval will result in Inf.
Demonstrating that integrating the square of a normal PDF can be done using pnorm:
height_dist <- c(177.5, 6.35)
f <- function(x) dnorm(x, height_dist[1], height_dist[2])
f1 <- function(x) f(x)*f(x)
integrate(f1, -Inf, 180)
#> 0.03159284 with absolute error < 1.5e-06
pnorm(180, height_dist[1], height_dist[2]/sqrt(2))/height_dist[2]/sqrt(pi)/2
#> [1] 0.03159284

Demonstrating the (mathematical) equivalence of the alternative version of expected_success_rate:
prob_height_given_null <- function(height) {
  dnorm(height, mean = height_dist[1], sd = height_dist[2])
}

prob_height_given_one <- Vectorize(function(height, threshold) {
  if (height >= threshold) {
    integrand <- function(x) {
      dnorm(x, mean = height_dist[1], sd = height_dist[2])
    }
    normaliser <- integrate(integrand, threshold, Inf)
    return(prob_height_given_null(height)/normaliser$value)
  }
  else {
    return(0)
  }
})

expected_success_rate <- Vectorize(function(thresh) {
  integrand_LHS <- function(h) {
    prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_null(h)
  }
  value_LHS <- integrate(integrand_LHS, -Inf, thresh)
  integrand_RHS <- function(h) {
    prob_height_given_null(h) * prob_height_given_one(h, thresh)}
  
  value_RHS <- integrate(integrand_RHS, thresh, Inf)
  
  return(value_LHS$value + value_RHS$value)
})

expected_success_rate2 <- function(thresh) {
  normalizer <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], height_dist[2], FALSE)
  value_LHS <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], s)
  value_RHS <- pnorm(thresh, height_dist[1], s, FALSE)/normalizer
  (value_LHS + value_RHS)/C
}

s <- height_dist[2]/sqrt(2)
C <- 2*height_dist[2]*sqrt(pi)
rbind(
  expected_success_rate(170:180),
  expected_success_rate2(170:180)
)
#>            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#> [1,] 0.05012842 0.05185676 0.05388938 0.05618745 0.05866877 0.06120528
#> [2,] 0.05012842 0.05185677 0.05388939 0.05618745 0.05866877 0.06120528
#>           [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]
#> [1,] 0.0636293 0.06574995 0.06737815 0.06835568 0.06858188
#> [2,] 0.0636293 0.06574995 0.06737815 0.06835568 0.06858188

Benchmarking:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  esr1 = expected_success_rate(170:180),
  esr2 = expected_success_rate2(170:180)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
#>  esr1 69075.9 70143.35 72992.418 71919.7 74143.90 123038.1   100
#>  esr2     5.5     6.20    45.632    10.8    18.85   3329.4   100

One final note. Integrating probability densities can be tricky in the tails. expected_success_rate2 maintains precision, while expected_success_rate does not.
expected_success_rate(120)
#> [1] 1.716383e-05
expected_success_rate2(120)
#> [1] 0.04442438


Thank you for this extremely helpful and detailed explanation.
